# Jenkins Pipeline EmailExt: Who are the "Suspects Causing Build to Begin Failing"?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins Pipeline job, when sending an email with the EmailExt plugin, one of the Recipient providers is "Suspects Causing the Build to Begin Failing".

The class name for this provider is `FirstFailingBuildSuspectsRecipientProvider`.

Who is this supposed to be in this list?  When I try using this provider, it sends no emails out.

Comment: Unfortunately this Provider seems to be broken within pipeline builds. Compare https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54940 and upvote if possible.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/recipients/FirstFailingBuildSuspectsRecipientProvider.java it is

A recipient provider that assigns ownership of a failing build to the set of developers (including any initiator) that committed changes that first broke the build.

Comment: Thanks for the link, yet the javadoc seems to describe Culprits then? Culprit's description directly in Jenkins UI is: "Sends email to the list of users who committed a change since the last non-broken build till now. This list at least always include people who made changes in this build, but if the previous build was a failure it also includes the culprit list from there.". Without inspecting the source codes of the providers, I cannot see the difference. I feel this part of the plugin is heavily under-documented and out-of-date (see their README for example), or isn't it?

Comment: OK, I think I get it now: "Suspects ..." are probably a subset of the "Culprits" - limited just to the very first failed build. Yet, I feel the docs would deserve an overhaul...